# KVM - libvirt qemu script make duplicates in iptables

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization, centos7, libvirt

OS: CentOS 7

Firewall: iptables

libvirt: 1.2.17

**Problem:** I used guide to make port forwarding from host to gues machines.
Link to guide: http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Forwarding_Incoming_Connections

When I activated that script, it works fine, but it makes duplicate lines in iptables also for regular and for nat rules.

How I can fix that?

**Example of script(standart script without changes, that I took from libvirt site. Seems like script has bug):**

```
Guest_name=crm-server
Guest_ipaddr=192.168.122.2
Host_ipaddr=1.1.1.1
Host_port=(  '1022' '1022' )
Guest_port=( '22' '22' )

length=$(( ${#Host_port[@]} - 1 ))
if [ "${1}" = "${Guest_name}" ]; then
   if [ "${2}" = "stopped" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
       for i in `seq 0 $length`; do
               iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -d ${Host_ipaddr} -p tcp --dport ${Host_port[$i]} -j DNAT --to ${Guest_ipaddr}:${Guest_port[$i]}
               iptables -D FORWARD -d ${Guest_ipaddr}/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport ${Guest_port[$i]} -j ACCEPT
       done
   fi
   if [ "${2}" = "start" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
       for i in `seq 0 $length`; do
               iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d ${Host_ipaddr} -p tcp --dport ${Host_port[$i]} -j DNAT --to ${Guest_ipaddr}:${Guest_port[$i]}
               iptables -I FORWARD -d ${Guest_ipaddr}/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport ${Guest_port[$i]} -j ACCEPT
       done
   fi
fi
```

**Example of firewall rules:**

```
[root@TOTORO ~]# iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.2/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.2/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
```

As you can see there is double line with

```
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.2/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Huh? What duplicate lines? I don't see any iptables firewall here?

Comment: done, you can see update